# Crear un archivo de texto de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: java

Necesito pasar un arreglo de objetos a un archivo de texto en java, pero sigo sin encontrar cómo hacerlo; esta es mi función donde se añade un nuevo objeto a mi arreglo:

```
public void darDeAlta(int serie, String marca, String modelo, int año, double 
                         precioDeLista, String color, String status, String motor) {
    Auto auto = new Auto(serie, marca, modelo, año, precioDeLista, color, status, motor);
   
    if (autos[0] == null) {

        autos[0] = auto;

    } else {
        Auto[] autosAuxiliar = new Auto[autos.length + 1];

        autosAuxiliar[autosAuxiliar.length - 1] = auto;

        for (int i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
            autosAuxiliar[i] = autos[i];
            
        }
        autos = autosAuxiliar;
    }
}
```

No tengo ni la más mínima idea de dónde empezar a crear el archivo, y cómo guardar mi arreglo en uno y que este se vaya actualizando con cada nuevo objeto agregado al arreglo con esta función, al igual de cómo eliminarlo del archivo si mi auto ya se vendió.

Mi clase auto:

```
public class Auto {
    private int serie,año;
    private String marca, modelo,color,motor,status;
    private double precioDeLista;
    CatalogoAutos autos[];
    //CatalogoAutos series[];

    public Auto(int serie, String marca, String modelo, int año, double precioDeLista, String color, String status, String motor){
        this.serie = serie;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.año = año;
        this.precioDeLista = precioDeLista;
        this.color = color;
        this.status = status;
        this.motor = motor;

    }


    public Auto(int serie){
        this.serie=serie;
    }

    Auto() {
  
    }


    public int getSerie() {
        return serie;
    }

    public void setSerie(int serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }

    public int getAño() {
        return año;
    }

    public void setAño(int año) {
       this.año = año;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(String motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getPrecioDeLista() {
        return precioDeLista;
    }

    public void setPrecioDeLista(float precioDeLista) {
        this.precioDeLista = precioDeLista;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Auto{" +
                "serie=" + serie +
                ", año=" + año +
                ", marca='" + marca + '\'' +
                ", modelo='" + modelo + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", motor='" + motor + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", precioDeLista=" + precioDeLista +
                ", autos=" + Arrays.toString(autos) +
                '}';
     }
}
```

y mi función para eliminar un auto del arreglo, que es lo que quisiera hacer también pero en el archivo de texto:

```
public void darDeBaja(int serie) {

    Auto[] autosAuxiliar = new Auto[autos.length - 1];
    boolean encontrado = false;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
        Auto auto = autos[i];
        if (auto.getSerie() != serie || encontrado) {
            autosAuxiliar[j] = autos[i];
            j++;
        } else {
            encontrado = true;
        }
    }
    if (encontrado) {
        autos = autosAuxiliar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que busques información de FileWriter, si tienes alguna duda vuelve con ella y estaremos encantados de ayudarte.

Comment: Has intentado usar alguna de las subclases de Writer?

Comment: Lo que necesitas es:

1. Almacenar tu array en un fichero de texto:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1375236/6300134

2. Leer el contenido del fichero de texto y almacenarlo en un array para trabajar con el:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100219/6300134

Una vez tengas claro como leer y escribir tus arrays de autos en ficheros, tendrías que poder eliminar y añadir una fila al mismo.

3. Eliminar una fila de un fichero de texto:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1381041/6300134

4. Añadir una línea a un fichero existente:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4614244/6300134

Comment: Una vez pruebes lo anterior, si tienes dudas, tal y como te comentó Enrique,  edita tu pregunta e intentamos ayudarte.